# How can I change label text in different class (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, class, label

Please, you can you help me, how can i change label text in diferent class?

Basic winform script:

```
public partial class buildEditor : Form
{
    public buildEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Label maxSkillPoint = new Label();
        maxSkillPoint.AutoSize = true;
        maxSkillPoint.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        maxSkillPoint.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
        maxSkillPoint.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(193)))), ((int)(((byte)(196)))), ((int)(((byte)(181)))));
        maxSkillPoint.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(528, 687);
        maxSkillPoint.Name = "maxSkillPoint";
        maxSkillPoint.Text = UniqueValue.spentSkillPoints.ToString();
        maxSkillPoint.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(maxSkillPoint);
    }

    public void maxSkillPoint_TextChanged(Form formInstance, string labelName)
    {
        // Get reference to the label
        var label = formInstance.Controls.Find(labelName, true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (null != label && label is Label)
        {
            (label as Label).Text = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

I created next class which will be change text for maxSkill text.

```
public class ChangeTextForMaxSkill()
{
    Button button = new Button();

    public ChangeTextForMaxSkill()
    {
        button.Click += new EventHandler(changeText);
    }

    private void changeText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get reference to the label
        var buildEditor = new buildEditor();
        buildEditor.maxSkillPoint_TextChanged(buildEditor, "maxSkillPoint");
    }
}
```

I really thx for all answers.

Comment: I edited my first post for call changeText();

Comment: Your button and its click event should be on the Form (BuildEditor) NOT on the ChangeTextForMaxSkill() class. Also the button is just for testing, add it on the visual designer. I don't know the rest of your project but check my updated answer for the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your naming conventions do not follow standard practices. Both class and method names should use uppercase first letters of words, not camel case as you have done. I have used proper naming conventions in my answer.

You have to pass an `instance` of your BuildEditor* form to your ChangeTextForMaxSkill.ChangeText() function.

Next, the label object maxSkill is not a property of your BuildEditor class. Therefore, you'd need to actually find a reference to that control within the form since you're dynamically adding it.

```
public partial class BuildEditor : Form
{
    public BuildEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label maxSkill = new Label();
        maxSkill.Name = "MaxSkil"; // need the ID to find it later (makes it easier)
        maxSkill.Location = new Point(1, 1);
        this.Controls.Add(maxSkill);
    }

    // This is just for testing; assumes you dragged a button from toolbox onto your
    // BuildEditor form in the Form Designer
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var changeTextForMaxSkill = new ChangeTextForMaxSkill();
        changeTextForMaxSkill.ChangeText(this, "MaxSkil");
    }

}

public class ChangeTextForMaxSkill
{
    public void ChangeText(Form formInstance, string labelName)
    {
        // Get reference to the label
        var label = formInstance.Controls.Find(labelName, true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (null != label && label is Label)
        {             
            (label as Label) .Text = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to test it, just add a button on your form and make the test in the button click handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var changeTextForMaxSkill = new ChangeTextForMaxSkill();
    changeTextForMaxSkill.ChangeText(this, "MaxSkil");
}
```

I've tested and this works :)

Comment: I tryit it now, wait please :)

Comment: its dont work for me, i edited my first post, can you check what i did bad?

Comment: not quite right on explanation of the naming conventions the casing is on visibility not object type, public items are usually upper case, protected is lower case and private either also lower case or lowercase and prefixed with _, this is so that at a glance you can see if the object your editing is local or global

Comment: @MikeT I used to do it that way but have over the years dropped underscores from my naming conventions and have seen others do the same. I was more speaking to camelCase vs PascalCase naming conventions in my answer, specifically as it relates to method names and class names. Was not trying to provide a dissertation on naming conventions :)

Answer (score 4):

**I got it very simple:**
Hand over the Label control in the constructor of your external class:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Yourclass{

    private Label UpdateLabel;
    public Yourclass (Label yourLabel)
    {
        this.UpdateLabel = yourlabel;
    }

    private void action()
    {
        //here is your update of the label
        UpdateLabel.Text = "Your text";
    }

}
```

In the form class, create an instance of "yourclass" and hand over the Label:

```
Yourclass cls = new Yourclass(Label1);
```

Comment: what would the alternative be if the class didn't use contracture?